# Eager Loading on autogenerated argument in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, loading, eager

I have this route call:

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController', ['except' => ['show']]);
```

So if I enter `/products/438/edit` it calls my edit method on controller, that is something like that:

```
 public function edit(Product $product){}
```

where `$product` is, correctly, my `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 438`

now my question is, what if I want to eager load a relation like prices()

I've tried:

```
$product = $product->with('prices');
```

and

```
$product = Product::find($product->id)->with('prices')
```

but without success. 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load relationships to an already existing model or collection using `load()`:

`$product->load('prices')`

Comment: Thank you, That's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `Product $product` and using resource controller, you're just injecting `Product` model. So, change function to:

```
public function edit(Product $product, $id)
```

You can eager load a relation with using of `with()` method:

```
$productData = $product->where('id', $id)->with('prices')->first();
```

Then you'll be able to access prices with something like this:

```
@foreach ($productData->prices as $price)
    {{ $price->sum }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, It works of course, but what is the point o using injection if I'll have again to use something like $product->where('id', $id) ? I could just pass the $id and do a Product::find($id)->with('prices') if I wanted that.

Comment: Dependency injection is just one of the many ways to use model class. When you pass an ID, you still need to get data from DB, because Laravel doesn't make this automatically.

Comment: When I pass just the ID I need to get data, when I inject, Product $product I don't.

Comment: You don't get the data. You just get an instance of a model class. It's like you'd do `$product = \App\Product;`. That's not the data, it's just an instance of a class.

Comment: Sorry if I insist but it is a Laravel Feature, when I do something like that it gives me a collection with the result of SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 438 so $product definitively has data. Look at this https://scotch.io/tutorials/cleaner-laravel-controllers-with-route-model-binding